What are the minor points on this 32-point compass?
I came across a sundial at St. Michael's Mount with a 32-point compass engraved on it. I have never seen the most minor 16 of these points marked on a compass before. What do these abbreviations stand for and what's their history? Here are the points from one quadrant:

S
SLW ?
SSW
SWLS ?
SW
SWLW ?
WSW
WLS ?
W

The ones with a ? are unfamiliar to me.

The letter "L" corresponds to the English "by", so that, for example, "SLW" stands for "South by West" and "SWLS" stands for "South West by South", as indicated in the section 32-wind compass rose in the Wikipedia article on the Points of the compass. The minor points "X by Y" are well-known, but I do not know what word in what language is actually abbreviated by "L".

Not a history of science question...

@Mauricio I wasn't quite sure which SE site this belonged on, if any, but feel free to migrate it if you can think of a better one.

Yep, it's a history of science question.

@Senex : just speculating, but maybe L stands for "line"? (cf. rhumb line)

Do you have a photo?  Maybe "L" is really "b": the two can look similar, as in https://www.alamy.com/compass-rose-vector-with-all-thirty-two-wind-directions-wind-rose-with-earth-symbol-in-the-middle-image560900737.html

@kimchilover I do, and on closer inspection it does look as though I might have misread it; it was slightly corroded.

@Senex I think you've got it - if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

As indicated in comments, what initially appeared to be a letter "L" was actually a corroded "b", corresponding to the English "by". For example, "SbW" stands for "South by West" and "SWbS" stands for "South West by South". There are sixteen directions named analogously, as described in the section 32-wind compass rose in the Wikipedia article on the Points of the compass.
